# angular-nestjs socket.io doesn't update if page doesn't refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io, nestjs

I am using Angular and NestJS with socket.io to create a chat application.
When I started saving data on my db, my Angular side stopped updating messages unless page refreshes.
I couldn't find a way to pass the `userid` on the server gateway in order to search in the db only chat of the user.

**Angular service**

```
  sendMessage(chat: Chat): void {
    this.socket.emit('sendMessage', chat)
  } //using it when a message is sent

  getNewMessage(): Observable<Chat[]> {
    return this.socket.fromEvent<any>('lastChats');
  } //using it onInit

  sendId(userId: number): void {
    this.socket.emit('loadMessages', userId);
  } //using it onInit
```

**NestJS Gateway**

```
@WebSocketGateway({ cors: { origin: ['http://localhost:4200'] } })
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Chat) private chatRepository: Repository<Chat>,
  ) { }

  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server

  async handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
      const chats = await this.chatRepository.createQueryBuilder('chat')
        .innerJoinAndSelect('chat.ally', 'ally')
        .innerJoinAndSelect('chat.talent', 'talent')
        .getMany();
      this.server.emit('lastChats', chats)
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log("Disconnected")
  }


  @SubscribeMessage('sendMessage')
  handleMessage(socket: Socket, chat: Chat) {
    if (chat.messagesJSON && chat.messagesJSON.trim() !== '') {
      this.chatRepository.save(chat)
      this.server.emit('newChat', chat)
    }

  @SubscribeMessage('loadMessages')
  
  async handleLoad(socket: Socket, id: number) {
    const chats = await this.chatRepository.createQueryBuilder('chat')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('chat.ally', 'ally')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('chat.talent', 'talent')
      .where('ally = :user OR talent = :user', { user: id })
      .getMany();
    this.server.emit('lastChats', chats)
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To send from angular to nestjs you can use

Angular:

this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_URL, {
      extraHeaders: {Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')},
    });


Nestjs: in the handleConnexion

    Const jwt =socket.handshake.headers.authorization

I think you can replace the token by usrerId
```